# Two-channel passive audio splitter

Tags: audio, mixer, bypass-capacitor

[image]

I have a Scarlett Solo like the one above and I need a way to split the output of the mix board's auxiliary output into two level controlled signals.

This Scarlett puts the instrument on the left channel and the microphone XLR - that I think is 600 Ω of impedance - on the right channel.

I was hoping to do this with a passive circuit and still be able to keep the Zout of the Aux at 100 kΩ if possible.

Would anyone have a circuit recommendation they could suggest?

Comment: The outputs of a mixer should be low impedance - the Behringer X-32 XLR line output impedance is 75 Ohms, and mic input impedance is 10K.

Comment: I guess I'm not taking into account the difference between the balanced and unbalanced chord aspects of the Auxiliary line output as well. :(

Comment: Guitar pickups and similar devices often are high impedance, but amplifier and mixer outputs will almost always be low impedance, whether balanced or unbalanced.

Comment: Sounds like you want to create 2 adjustable aux sends from the back panel line outputs, completely passive, no batteries. Do you want to keep the adjustments for left and right channels matched for each send? If so, I'd suggest two stereo, 1K, audio taper potentiometers. If not, then four ordinary potentiometers. You should put it all in a metal box to reduce the possibility of hum.

Answer (score 1):

So here is a picture of the schematic that seems to work with it and there didn't seem to be any deterioration in the sound quality. Thank all of you for answering my texts.

[image]